# subscribe to sns topic throwing authorization error

Tags: amazon-sns, aws-sts

I am trying to subscribe to sns topic using postman, I am following this [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html#:%7E:text=Example%20of%20an%20Amazon%20Kinesis%20Data%20Firehose%20delivery%20stream%20subscription). I am getting following error authorization error even though I have added both of the below permission in my IAM role:

```
Grant AmazonSNSFullAccess to the appropriate role (my case its AmazonLendingAPIRole)
Create an inline policy to allow sns:Subscribe to all resources
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "sns:Subscribe"
  ],
  "Resource": [
     "*"
 ]
}
```

Error I am getting:

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://sns.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-03-31/">
<Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>AuthorizationError</Code>
    <Message>User: arn:aws:sts::******:assumed-role/AmazonLendingAPIRole/Assume123 is not authorized to perform: SNS:Subscribe on resource: arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:********:glm-event-feed-**** because no resource-based policy allows the SNS:Subscribe action</Message>
</Error>
<RequestId>198d5945-****-52d8-a6d6-0590e0189fcd</RequestId>
```

What I have been doing:

First I am getting temporary credentials using AssumeRole action from sts service. After getting those temp credentials I am making api call to subscribe sns topic like below:

[image]

this is my post request to the end point:

```
https://sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Subscribe&TopicArn=arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:********:glm-event-feed-*****&Protocol=https&Endpoint=https://eo9ihuu8q2xhluf.m.pipedream.net&Version=2010-03-31
```

Not sure what else I am missing here?

Comment: Try setting Resource in your IAM policy to  `:aws:sns:*:replace-with-your-account-id:*` and see if it helps